# Как сравнить строку с регулярным выражением?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Я хочу сравнить эти две строки с помощью регулярных выражений. Для этого использую `regex_match` и код из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33185526/8313610). Но почему-то сравнение возвращает `false`. По возможности лучше не изменять строку `not*.exe`, потому что на её месте может быть строка подобного типа и добавлять ,например, экранирование спец символов( или другие дополнительные символы для регулярного выражения) в разные места будет трудно. Можно ли универсально мэтчить имена программ, как в этом примере?

```
    std::string string("notepad.exe");
    std::regex regex("not*.exe");
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::regex_match(string, regex);
```

Как правильно сравнивать подобные строки,когда одна из них известна целиком, а другая включает в себя регулярные выражения?

Comment: Надо получить правильный результат, не изменяя неправильное регулярное выражение? :)

Comment: `not*.exe` - не та регулярка которая вам нужна

Comment: @timur, а почему тогда она работает в cmd для нахождения блокнота ?

Comment: @Elvin потому что в cmd не регулярные выражения

Comment: @timur, но чтобы работать с таким , нужны регулярные выражения , верно? Просто эта строку я перехватил из winapi вызова

Comment: Предлагаю отказаться от регулярок и воспользоваться [кодом проверки соответствия маске](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483724/178988).

Comment: Из каких символов могут состоять имена ваших программ? Может ли быть `notepad.exe.exe` и т.п.? Приведите примеры, что надо матчить, а что нет в вопросе

Comment: @Qwertiy, хорошо проверяет, спасибо за ссылку на ваш ответ, а то я не мог нормально ни сформулировать, ни найти подобный вопрос. Можете оставить ссылку на ваш ответ в этом вопросе, я выберу его как решение?

Comment: @Elvin, для регулярки, которую вы пытаетесь использовать, нужна функция [fnmatch](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch), а не regex()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Преобразование строки для вставки (или преобразования) в регулярку делается добавлением `\` перед символами `[]{}.()?+*^$\|`.
- В твоём случае `?` надо не экранировать, а заменять на `.`; а `*` - на `.*`.
- Надо не забыть добавить маркеры начала `^` и конца `$` строки в начало и конец регулярки. В группу можно не заключать, поскольку внутри ветвлений не используется. Если бы использовались, то надо было бы обернуть в незахватываемую группу `(?:)`.

PS: А вообще, вместо того, чтобы всё это делать, я бы воспользовался соответствующим [алгоритмом проверки соответствия имени файла маске](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483724/178988).

Comment: Как с помощью алгоритма по ссылке *универсально мэтчить имена программ*?

Comment: @dIm0n, метчить можно что угодно, что укажешь в маске. Автор спросил про маску, я ответил про маску. Спросил бы про glob - пришлось бы искать glob. Ну и он сам в комменте написал, что этот алгоритм ему полностью подошёл. Про преобразование маски в регулярку, о котором говорится в вопросе, я тоже написал. Чего ещё надо?

Comment: @dIm0n, видимо под программами понимаются exe-файлы, а всякие com, pif, bat идут лесом.

Comment: *Автор спросил про маску* - вот именно, что спрашивал он не про маску, а про регулярные выражения. А потом добавил в вопрос *Можно ли универсально мэтчить имена программ, как в этом примере?* Точное значение этого вопроса мне неясно, но я это понимаю как матчить имена файлов, начинающихся с каких-то символов. Но дело в том, что имена файлов могут состоять не из любых символов, а значит `*` из алгоритма по ссылке тут не подходит

Comment: @dIm0n, но при этом в вопросе написана маска. Я ответил на вопрос так, как я его понимаю. Автор прямым текстом написал, что мой ответ верный. Вопроса "как составить регулярное выражение для поиска программ?" не задавалось. А если бы задавался, то префикса `not` в вопросе бы не было. В Windows `*` и `?` не могут использоваться как часть имени файла, а такие маски поддерживаются в winapi.

Comment: *но при этом в вопросе написана маска.* - ну лично я вижу 4 повторения "регулярные выражения" + метку [tag:регулярные-выражения] в вопросе и 0 упоминаний маски + фразу, которая не позволяет использовать любой символ `*` из масок по ссылке. То, что это помогло ТС, отлично. Но стоит тогда отредактировать вопрос, чтобы люди из поисковика приходили сюда за маской для любых символов либо вообще сделать дубликатом вашего вопроса. *А если бы задавался, то префикса not в вопросе бы не было* - можно искать имена файлов с префиксом `not`, почему нет

Answer (score 2):

У вас неправильное регулярное выражение, экранирование символов для строковых литералов С++ тут ни при чём.

Попробуйте:

```
not.*\.exe
```

Тест https://regexr.com/59juu

В коде:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

int main() {
    std::string string{"notepad.exe"};
    std::regex regex{R"~(not.*\.exe)~"};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::regex_match(string, regex);
}
```

Если вы хотите матчить имена программ, то регулярка должна быть сложнее. Если так, то уточните условие согласно описанию метки [регулярные-выражения](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)